# How to send a variable with formData using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I send a variable with formdata? I am sure it is really simple but I've tried some things and it is not working. I am using the blueimp fileupload plugin by the way.

My code now:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    var url = window.location.hostname === 'site.nl/demo/server/php/' ?
                '//site.nl/' : 'demo/server/php/';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        formData: [
          { name: 'custom_dir', value: '/fileupload/<?PHP echo $_GET['bedrijf'] ?>/<?PHP echo $_GET['alias'] ?>/' },
          { name: 'cat_id', value: '<?PHP echo $gtc['id']; ?>'},
          { name: 'name', value: $( "#filename" ).val()},
      ],
      add: function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('<button/>').text('Uploaden starten').addClass('font-15 btn btn-secondary btn-lg waves-effect btnadd fullwidth')
                .appendTo('.uploadbutton')
                .click(function () {
                    data.submit();
                });
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
</script>
```

This is the part that is empty:

```
{ name: 'name', value: $( "#filename" ).val()},
```

The echoed php values work fine, but this one is empty.

I've also tried it this way:

```
var filename = $( "#filename" ).val();
```

And then below

```
{ name: 'name', value: filename},
```

This is my input field:

```
<input class="form-control" id="filename" type="text" name="filename" value="">
```

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: i think formData should be an instance of FormData. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Comment: @vicbyte Both. Uploading already works, but I am trying to send a name so users can change the name of the uploaded file, that name is then saved in my database.

Comment: Yes I used `alert($( "#filename" ).val());` inside my click function, and it shows the input correctly.

Comment: @vicbyte Changed both the name of the variable and the name inside formdata, nothing :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<input class="form-control" id="filename" type="text" name="filename" value="">

var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('filename'));
```

send image,audio,file or text together;

Comment: This does not work. I don't even have a form element. My plugin that I use, uses formData.

Comment: u need read this!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append